# Json to csv in Node Js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, export-to-csv, node-modules

I have a JSON data which want to download it as csv file. How to achieve this in node js? Does NodeJs has some predefined modules for this?

P.S. I also want to add some formatting such as adding Headers like MONTHLY REPORT etc. adding row colors etc.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Comment: See also these questions: [How to convert JSON array to CSV using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38244285/5764553), [node.js: Convert json array to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27817645/5764553), and [Json to csv in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27481929/5764553). (Last one isn't as closely related.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP shows no effort / attempt

Comment: Some other questions: [Nested JSON to CSV format Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35245113/5764553) and [How to parse JSON object to CSV file using json2csv nodejs module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20620771/5764553)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON array to CSV using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244285/how-to-convert-json-array-to-csv-using-node-js)

Comment: By the way, I don't think that CSV can do row colors. It's pretty much a text-only format. The first line is usually where the headers are, but again, I don't think you can do any special formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js json2csv module would work

Here are some code examples:

Install it through npm

```
npm install --save json2csv
```

Use it in your node.js app:

```
const json2csv = require('json2csv').parse;
const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
const opts = { fields };

try {
  const csv = json2csv(myData, opts);
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this how we should group some particular field under one headings in csv is like:

```
      Usernames
Name1 | Name2 | Name3
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about you guys, but i like small packages that just work as expected without a lot of extra configuration, try using **jsonexport**, works really well with objects, arrays, .. and its fast!

Install

```
npm i --save jsonexport
```

Usage

```
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

jsonexport({lang: 'Node.js', module: 'jsonexport'}, function(err, csv){
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(csv);
});
```

https://github.com/kauegimenes/jsonexport